# Selenium python refreshing and wait until element visible

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import schedule

def refresh_page():
    driver.refresh()

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mask2")
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        schedule.every().minute.at(":01").do(refresh_page)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)  

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder = '出售數量']").clear()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder = '出售數量']").send_keys(amount)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.bg-red.ivu-btn.ivu-btn-default.ivu-btn-long").click()
```

I have been trying to make this code refresh and wait until the element is visible, the problem is I can't seem to make it stop refreshing even though the element is already visible

I tried changing the codes around but it's still the same result.

Comment: Could you please provide a site link? I would like to try the selenium js method

Answer (score 0):

how your second while gonna stop?
is schedule.run_pending() stop the while?
i think you dont need second while in except.

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mask2")
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        schedule.every().minute.at(":01").do(refresh_page)
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: when I remove the while loop for the time first problem encountered is it doesn't refresh at the specific time I wanted, the second problem is that it just skips the loop and goes straight into the next line.